# MySQL Workbench Setup New Connection on Manjaro KDE

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-workbench, manjaro

I am working on a Linux Manjaro KDE. Now the issue is I cannot set up connection with MySQL Workbench. I have tried a ton of other advice through wiki's, forums, and even youtube videos. The problem persists with no avail. I have reset the password using:

sudo su

whoami

passwd

I changed the password due to research telling me that mysql has a default password that can interfere with logging into a server. Because I am on Manjaro, there is no wizard to alter this so I felt I had to do it manually. The problem is permissions. Whenever I enter the password, I get an error code and get the same code if I do not use the password. This is what I am getting even when entering the password I created:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change mysql root password, not system user root password

Comment: When I attempted that, I received the same type of error in my Konsole/Terminal

Comment: So, I have been tinkering around and discovered that with Windows and Mac, they have access to an uninstall Wizard where you can change the built-in password. Unfortunately, Linux does not seem to have the same Wizard. I have run out of options on how I can solve this issue. Please let me know if anyone has figured it out.

Comment: First - try to connect with mysqk client from console: `mysql -uroot -pyourpassword`